# Large prime gap between $10^{4999}-20777$ to $10^{4999}+22669$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

According to my calculation, the numbers $10^{4999}-20777$ and $10^{4999}+22669$ are consecutive (very probable) primes.

> 1) Are the numbers really prime ?
>
> 2) Are the primes really consecutive ?

I did not check all the numbers in one session, so I might have forgotten to
check some numbers.

Comment: The average gap in prime numbers of this size is $11,511$, this gap ($43,446$) is about $3.8$ times larger.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  If someone simply answers Yes to either question, how will that (by itself) help you?

Comment: Mathematica says that both are primes.

Comment: It's easy enough to check, and took 18 minutes to verify those are consecutive PRPs (e.g. `n-prev_prime(n)=20777` and `next_prime(n)-n=22669`).  Rather than writing so many "Dear LazyWeb" letters, it sounds like you need to get Primo so you can check primality yourself, and just be more patient with Pari/GP.

Comment: @DanaJ My PARI/GP-program runs under Windows and the ispseudoprime-command is slow for large numbers. It takes about $5.6$ seconds on my machine for $5000$-digit primes, and it does not seem to include trial division. Isprime and Ispseudoprime are slow, if the number is really prime. Of course, I can sieve out small factors manually, but still it takes long to find new $5000$-digit primes. Is there any possibility to speed up the search ?

Comment: @DanaJ The forprime or parforprime-command is fast for small primes, but quite useless for large primes.

Answer (score 4):

You should mention what testing methods you used.

You likely have a pair of [Probable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime).  From the [PRP Records](http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/prptop.php), you'd need to run the following tests:

- N does not have any prime factor up to 2^32.
- N cannot be trivially written into a product.
- Take 3 square-free consecutive bases such that $(b_1/N)=(b_2/N)=(b_3/N)= -1$. $N$ should be such that $b_1^{(N-1)/2}=b_2^{(N-1)/2}=b_3^{(N-1)/2}= -1 (\mod N)$.
- Take a prime base such that $(b/N)= -1$ and $b<>b_1<>b_2<>b_3$. $N$ should pass the strong test in base b.

Mathematica's PrimeQ uses probable prime methods.  As of yet, there are no known examples of a composite number passing all of the current probable prime tests -- but 15 years ago, there was another suite of tests and two counterexamples were found, which led to the new suite of tests.

Comment: That is a method, but quite unusual.  Typically a BPSW test is used these days, with no trial division requirements (but usually is done because it saves time for most composites).  Pinch's paper came out in 1993 (22 years ago).  Maple switched to BPSW   Mathematica at the time claimed to be running a BPSW variant but, according to Pinch, was incorrectly implemented.  According to current documentation PrimeQ currently uses a BPSW variant and adds a base-3 M-R test -- hopefully with the correct Lucas test this time.  Pari/GP switched from 10 random-base M-R tests to BPSW in June 2002

Comment: I don't quite understand some of this.  I understand the first and second criteria but not the third or forth.  In the third what is the / symbol in (b1 / N)?  I'm guessing it's not division since it's not going to be an integer unless it's a multiple of N.  Also why is it equal to -1?  Is it the modulus function?  Also what is the <> symbol in the fourth criteria?  Thanks!